# BLE connection not stable

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I have used esp32 to send sensor data to raspberry pi using BLE with help of bluepy library . In this, I am getting error of disconnecting from devices. can anyone provide  me help why I am getting the errors.

Here is my python  code for raspberry pi:

```
import binascii
import struct
import time
from bluepy.btle import UUID, Peripheral

temperature_uuid = UUID(6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E)

p = Peripheral("24:0A:C4:02:D1:DA", "public")

try:
    ch = p.getCharacteristics(uuid=temp_uuid)[0]
    while 1:
        val = binascii.b2a_hex(ch.read())
        print str(val)
        time.sleep(1)

finally:
    p.disconnect()
```

error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ble_test.py", line 9, in <module>
   p = Peripheral("24:0A:C4:83:14:B6", "public")
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bluepy/btle.py", 
   line 353, in __init__
   self._connect(deviceAddr, addrType, iface)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bluepy/btle.py", 
   line 402, in _connect
   "Failed to connect to peripheral %s, addr type: %s" % (addr, 
   addrType))
   bluepy.btle.BTLEException: Failed to connect to peripheral 
   24:0A:C4:83:14:B6, addr type: public
```

Comment: The shown traceback is not about disconnecting, it is about you couldn't connect to device.

Comment: `https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/83` with Could you try opening a second terminal window, and running `sudo hcidump -t`

Comment: You show two different device mac addresses 24:0A:C4:83:14:B6 and 24:0A:C4:02:D1:DA - do you have multiple devices? If so please show the actual code that receives from multiple devices - also - are you sure it isn't the esp32 falling over? Do you have some log or trace from that? Also what is/are the esp32s running - the standard firmware, lua, micropython, etc...?

Comment: yes I have used multiple device and I used arduino to code esp32. I am able to get data  continuously in mobile using nrfconnect app